# I got an error : socket error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, sockets

This is my code:

```
import serial
import time
import socket
ip = str('url')
port = int(6090)
err = 0
try:
    mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    mySocket.connect((ip, port))
    while 1:
        arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
        sensorValue = arduino.readline()
        mySocket.sendall(sensorValue)
except socket.error, msg:
    mySocket.close()
    print 'socket error', msg
mySocket.close
```

After I run this program, I got this message "socket error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution".
Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you think it's lying?

Comment: Please indent your code correctly! In Python indentation is important.

Comment: Speak to your network administrators about getting more reliable network systems — or perhaps upgrade your computer to a more reliable system.  You have a transient problem in your networking and name resolution; that means the problem will resolve itself (probably) soon.

Answer (score 1):

The root issue is that `/etc/resolv.conf` is only read at python startup. To force a refresh of the resolve table, you can run this (on linux):

```
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libc.so.6')
res_init = libc.__res_init
res_init()
```